# Реализовать такой же способ сортировки, только для int

Tags: java, javafx

Есть у меня ObservableList, который с файла сохраняет данные типов String, int, int. Все это добро у меня отображается в TableView. Так вот. По всем этим параметрам таблицу надо отсортировать. По имени получилось так:

```
package sample;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class CarNameComparator implements Comparator<Car> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Car o1, Car o2) {
        if(o1 != null && o2 != null){
            if(null != o1.getName() && null != o2.getName()){
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Name";
    }
}
```

но вот с числами так же работать не хочет. Как это можно реализовать с интами?

В таблице все сортируется так:

```
Comparator<Car> nameComp = new CarNameComparator();
FXCollections.sort(tableView.getItems(),nameComp);
```

Файл выглядит типу:
Audi 250 4000
BMW 280 5500
Mersedes 300 4500
и тд.

Comment: Это снова я) Возможно проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь сравнивать примитивы. Заврапьте `int` в `Integer` (т.к. `implements Comparable<Integer>`)

Comment: Условно так: `new Integer(o1.getSomeInt()).compareTo(new Integer(o2.getSomeInt()))`. Это не очень красиво, поэтому можно просто прописать свою логику, ведь при сравнении всего лишь нужно вернуть одно из трёх значений `-1, 1 или 0`

Comment: Вспомнил вариант получше: `return Integer.compare( o1.getSomeInt(), o2.getSomeInt() )`

Answer (score 1):

Можно установить Compаrator на соответствующий столбец:

```
    TableColumn<Car, Integer> numberColumn = new TableColumn<Car, Integer>("Some number");

    numberColumn.setComparator(new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
            return Integer.compare(i1, i2);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Вроде нет ошибок, но в таблице не меняется ничего